# Regular expression for matching HH:MM - HH:MM

Tags: regex, forms

I'd need a regex that would work like:

> HH:MM-HH:MM

And I've found one regex here but that is just for HH:MM

```
(^([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$)
```

Anyone how can help me since it's not my storgest area. I will use it in HTML-forms.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is not a code/SQL/regex writing service, where you post a list of your requirements and language of choice and a code monkey churns out code for you. We're more than happy to help, but we expect you to make an effort to solve the problem yourself first. Once you've done so, you can explain the problem you're having, include the **relevant** portions of your work, and ask a specific question, and we'll try to help. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

This question seems quite simple to answer, but not everyone can make sense of the mess of letters that is RegEx. I recommend you sit down for a few hours on https://www.regexone.com which I find to be quite great for learning RegEx and use https://www.regex101.com to analyze Regular Expressions.

As for your question, I believe this is what you are looking for

```
(?:^(?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]-(?:[0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]$)
```

which you can test at this [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/pQYjHb/1)

Happy learning.

Comment: Thanks, I will try these pages. And thanks for the code!

Answer (score 0):

[See regex in use here](https://regex101.com/r/xNK8RV/1)

```
^([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)-([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)$
```

- `([01]?\d|2[0-3])` Matches any number in the range of `0-23` allowing single or double digits (leading 0)
- `:` Match this literally
- `([0-5]\d)-` Matches any number in the range of `00-59`
- `-` Match this literally
- Repeat the above (minus the last match of `-`)

With the `pattern` attribute, you can drop the anchors `^` and `$` as the following snippet suggests

```html
<form>
  <input type=text pattern="([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)-([01]?\d|2[0-3]):([0-5]\d)" placeholder="00:00-00:00">
  <input type=submit>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!